# Invalid max count in grep function

Tags: linux, unix, find, grep, systemtime

If I do a `find . -mmin -1` I get 'myfile' which was modified in last one minute.

But when I want to search a particular string in that file by doing

```
grep 'myString' myfile -mmin -1
```

I get the error `invalid max count`

I also tried

```
find . -name "myfile" -exec grep 'myString' myfile -mmin -5
```

I get the error `find: missing argument to -exec`

So my question is `How do I grep or cat only the changes within a file which happened in last 5 mins. Now that I know the file name which was modified during that period.`

Suggestions? Thanks in adv.

Comment: I think with this one, you came closest: `find . -name "myfile" -exec grep 'myString' myfile -mmin -5`, however, if you need to execute the grep from find, it must be `find . -mmin -1 -exec grep -H "mystring" {} \;` where the {} are where to insert the filename, and \; terminates the grep command. In this way, find will search for new files and execute grep on each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grep doesn't have an mmin argument as far as I can see. It *does* have a -m argument with a number parameter. `grep 'myString' myfile -m3` will stop after 3 lines containing myString. So, the error message means that 'min' in `-mmin` is not a valid maximum count.

Answer (score 9):

**grep something ***

Error:

> grep: invalid max count

Verify that you have a file with a leading dash in the name in the current directory.
The file name might be taken for an option.

For example:

```
grep something // okay

touch -- -mmin
```

**grep something **

> grep: invalid max count

Workaround:

**grep -- something **

From `man getopt`:

> Each  parameter  after  a `--` parameter is always interpreted as a non-option parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this when forgetting to escape a dash in the grep string:

Example:

```
history | grep '-m yum'
grep: invalid max count

history | grep '\-m yum'
...
sudo ansible workstations -m yum --fork=20 -a 'name=zsh state=latest'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is to combine `grep` command and `find` command into single command:

```
grep "search-patten" $(find . -mmin -5)
```

This command will find all matched lines to "search-patten" in all modified files under current directory younger than 5 minutes ago.

```
grep "search-patten" $(find . -mmin +5)
```

This command will find all matched lines to "search-patten" in all modified files  under current directory older than 5 minutes ago.